# How to avoid the max connection limit?

Tags: tcp, connection, ip, limit

Dear StackOverflow members,

I was wondering, let's say with Whatsapp... you're continously connected to their servers.(Using TCP)
And assuming there's a max of 65535 connections/port, how do they avoid that limit?

Seeing as that'd mean once a server hits 65535 one time it'll always stay on that and never go down, as everyone's phone simply stays connected.

I'm not sure if you guys understand my question, but if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Kind regards,

Rene Roosen

Comment: "assuming there's a max of 65535 connections/port" Why are you making that assumption? As your question depends on it you should at least motivate it. What makes you think there's a limit on connections per port at all?

Answer (score 0):

Any large website wouldn't rely on one server. They'd usually use a load balancing proxy (commercial or open-source ones like ATS or HA proxy) and have several servers behind those. Those proxies have mechanisms to scale to much higher connections.

As long as the 4-tuple is unique (source-ip, source-port, dest-ip, dest-port), a proxy can handle the connection provided other resources (memory, cpu, etc.) are available. They don't restrict traffic to 64k connections/port.

Comment: And then again does this proxy also run over a huge amount of servers?

Comment: Usually runs on custom hardware (Netscaler, F5, etc.) or on a really powerful server.

Comment: But let's say someone makes a TCP connection which then goes through the load balancing proxy, wouldn't that mean the load balancing proxy keeps a TCP connection open with the servers beneath and then eventually the servers beneath will again be on there 65535 limit?

Comment: They'd have "several servers" behind the proxy.

Comment: @ReneRoosen *What* 65535 limit? You made it up.

Comment: I'm guessing OP was hitting the default fd limit.

Comment: I just checked back on this question and it appears very vague. What I likely was refering to was that there are only 65535 that you can bind to per IP. Regardless, question was definitely not asked well.

I apologize for any confusion.